# How to collect array of emitted values from Observable.from?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

So in Rxjs, I have bunch of code,

```
return Observable.from(input_array)
           .concatMap((item)=>{
               //this part emits an Observable.of<string> for each item in the input_array
           })
           .scan((output_array:string[],each_item_output_array:string)=>{
               return output_array.push(each_item_output_array) ;
           });
```

But apparently this is wrong, the scan will break the code inside the concatMap, so I want to know how to collect the output array of each item in the observable `from` operator?

Comment: What do you mean emits a string? The `project` function passed to [`concatMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) is supposed to return an observable, a promise or an array - not a string.

Comment: @cartant, it's the Observable of string, it is actually a string, of course also the observable.

Comment: Actually, I take that back - you can return a string. `concatMap` will iterate it and emit its individual characters.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In your call to [`scan`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-scan) you have not specified a seed for the accumulator. In that circumstance, the first value is used as a seed. For example:

```js
Rx.Observable
  .from(["a", "b", "c"])
  .scan((acc, value) => acc + value)
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

In your snippet, the first value is not an array, so you cannot call `push` on it. To accumulate the values into an array, you can specify an array seed like this:

```js
Rx.Observable
  .from(["a", "b", "c"])
  .concatMap(value => Rx.Observable.of(value))
  .scan((acc, value) => {
    acc.push(value);
    return acc;
  }, []) // Note that an empty array is use as the seed
  .subscribe(value => console.log(JSON.stringify(value)));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Although, for some use cases, it would be preferable to not mutate the array:

```js
Rx.Observable
  .from(["a", "b", "c"])
  .concatMap(value => Rx.Observable.of(value))
  .scan((acc, value) => [...acc, value], [])
  .subscribe(value => console.log(JSON.stringify(value)));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Note that `scan` emits an array for each value that it receives. If you only want a single array emitted when the observable completes, you can use the `toArray` operator instead:

```js
Rx.Observable
  .from(["a", "b", "c"])
  .concatMap(value => Rx.Observable.of(value))
  .toArray()
  .subscribe(value => console.log(JSON.stringify(value)));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I could upvote this a hundred times I would. toArray solved a problem I'd been working on all day. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Be carefull with this code:

```
      const obs = Rx.Observable
      .from(["a", "b", "c"])
      .concatMap(value => Rx.Observable.of(value))
      .scan((acc, value) => {
        acc.push(value);
        return acc;
      }, []); 
      obs.subscribe(value => console.log(JSON.stringify(value)));
      obs.subscribe(value => console.log(JSON.stringify(value)));
```

Result will be a bit unexpected:

```
 ["a"]
 ["a","b"]
 ["a","b","c"]
 ["a","b","c","a"]
 ["a","b","c","a","b"]
 ["a","b","c","a","b","c"]
```

"acc" variable is reference object and each subscriber gets stream data and adds data to the same object again.
It might be a lot of solutions for avoiding it, this is creation new object when stream data is received again :

```
    var obs = Rx.Observable
          .from(["a", "b", "c"])
          .concatMap(value => Rx.Observable.of(value))
          .scan((acc, value) => {
          //clone initial value
            if (acc.length == 0) {

                   acc = [];
                }
            acc.push(value);
            return acc 
          }, []); // Note that an empty array is use as the seed
          obs.subscribe(value => console.log(JSON.stringify(value)));
          obs.subscribe(value => console.log(JSON.stringify(value)));
```

result as expected:

```
 ["a"]
 ["a","b"]
 ["a","b","c"]
 ["a"]
 ["a","b"]
 ["a","b","c"]
```

I hope it saves a lot time for someone

Comment: Instead of creating a new empty array when the first element comes, you can return a new array on every iteration: ```return [...acc, value]```. This is a more functional approach and browsers are quite good in optimizing this.

Comment: @sashee it is good point, there is lot of solution and  the main idea is breaking reference to object with array for each stream data

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `bufferCount(count)`  if you know the length of the input array you can get a single output containing that number of items. Cleaner syntax than having to remember how to use `scan`.

Note: If you don't know the size (although in your example you would) then `count` represents a maximum - but this may have resource constraints so don't just make it 99999.

```
 const array = source$.pipe(bufferCount(10));
```

In my case I had a list of 'operations' being executed and I knew the total number of steps in advance, so `bufferCount` worked quite well. However be sure to carefully consider error conditions

```
 // one approach to handling errors that still returns an output array
 // only use this if a single failure shouldn't stop the collection
 const array = source$.pipe(
                    map((result) => ({ hasError: false, result: result }),
                    catchError((err) => ({ hasError: true, error: err }),
                    bufferCount(10));
```

The decision on how to handle errors will vary greatly based on what your observables actually are - but the point here is to show `bufferCount()` as an option.

(There are other `buffer` operations available too)